# Typo3Fluid FE crashes with 500 if cache files are created, error on: getViewHelper()

Tags: php, caching, fluid, flux, typo3-6.2.x

I have upgraded Typo3 from 6.1.x with FED to 6.2.17 and the following typo3Fluid extensions:

- builder (1.0.0)
- fluidcontent (4.3.3)
- fluidpages (3.3.1)
- flux (7.2.3)
- vhs (2.3.3)

I have done a lot of template migrations, guided by the migration documents on the Typo3Fluid website for [FED](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/appendix/migration/from-fed.html) and [Flux](https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/appendix/migration/to-flux-70.html) but my System crashes if I put them into the theme provider extension.

I already tried the example templates from the fluid builder only, and they seem to work, but if i add one of the refactored templates errors happen.

1. The Backend is loading/rendering very very slow but i don't mind that currently
2. The Frontend shows error 500 and in the php log it tells me `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getViewHelper() on a non-object in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\[Project]\web\typo3temp\Cache\Code\fluid_template\ThemeProvider_Content_action_render_eed9cf578f1072dfb942bb46036bee78de97954d.php on line 17`

I looked into 2 a bit further and the specific line shows `$self->getViewHelper(...` but `$self` is never defined in that processed file. And i'm out of ideas on that.

```
    public function getLayoutName(\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
// Rendering ViewHelper FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Extension\LoadedViewHelper
        $arguments53 = array();
        $arguments53['extensionName'] = 'fluidcontent_core';
        $arguments53['then'] = 'ContentCore';
        $arguments53['else'] = 'Content';
        $renderChildrenClosure54 = function () use ($renderingContext, $self) {
            return NULL;
        };
        $viewHelper55 = $self->getViewHelper('$viewHelper55', $renderingContext, 'FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Extension\LoadedViewHelper');
        $viewHelper55->setArguments($arguments53);
        $viewHelper55->setRenderingContext($renderingContext);
        $viewHelper55->setRenderChildrenClosure($renderChildrenClosure54);
// End of ViewHelper FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\Extension\LoadedViewHelper

        return $viewHelper55->initializeArgumentsAndRender();
    }
```

Here's the FCE I tried it with:

```
<div xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
     f:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/fluid-6.2.0.xsd"
     xmlns:flux="http://typo3.org/ns/FluidTYPO3/Flux/ViewHelpers"
     flux:schemaLocation="https://fluidtypo3.org/schemas/flux-7.2.2.xsd">

    <f:layout name="Content"/>

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="box2col_1-1" label="Container: 2 Spalten 1/1" >
            <flux:grid>
                <flux:grid.row>
                    <flux:grid.column name="col-foo" colPos="0" style="width:50%;"/>
                    <flux:grid.column name="col-bar" colPos="1" style="width:50%;"/>
                </flux:grid.row>
            </flux:grid>
        </flux:form>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Preview">
        2 Spalten mit gleicher Breite
        <br/>
        <flux:widget.grid/>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Main">
        <div>
            <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
                <flux:content.render render="1" area="col-foo"/>
            </div>

            <div class="small-6 large-6 columns">
                <flux:content.render render="1" area="col-bar"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </f:section>
</div>
```

Hope you have a new idea or maybe a solution on this issue, thanks in advance.

Cheers

Tobias

---

**Some News** about that, i changed the FCE a bit according to documentation on FLUX and FLUID and included the shema a bit different (code example above is updated).

Now the Backend is much better and even the frontend renders everything after i delete the cache folder but on second reload, if the cache files have been created, the issue 2. still happens.

**The Backend Problem** is addressed in this question:
[How do I know which file system apache can not access on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35059636/how-do-i-know-which-file-system-apache-can-not-access-on-windows)